# Does it affect site performance and SEO to use onclick handler instead of links?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, seo

To call new windows, JavaScript functions and other internal stuff I've been using `onclick`  along with `cursor: pointer` rather than using links with JavaScript in the `href` attribute.  This prevents `#` from appearing in the URL in the status bar.

When linking to other pages I use normals hrefs with a friendly URL.

#### My Questions

- Does using `onclick` instead of JavaScript in a link's `href` affect performance?
- Does it affect search engine rankings?

Comment: Why the votes to close? It's terribly worded, but the underlying question is still pretty clear; a quick edit would rescue this question, although it's surely a duplicate.

Comment: well... im not a good english speaker or writer... thnx for the edit! @Andy E

Answer (score 2):

To start off, it's a bad idea to practice this, because users who have disabled JavaScript cannot navigate at your site any more ([NoScript](http://noscript.net)).

That aside, it's not possible to rightclick, and bookmark/open the page in a new window.

If you don't want these "internal pages" to be indexed, add `rel="nofollow"` to your links.

Comment: I see... but, Its out of my concept to make dynamics webpages wtithout javascript ( i kwon, i got lots to learn yet...) A good examples is here, the stackoverflow ...

The second part:
Yeah, its like this, most of those calls are for internal pages, but even, to UI interface has a few of those calls, like the photo and video's viewer. 
in that context, i have to introduce a new question: how to desapear with the '#' from URL and and status bar ? @Rob W ? .. i also dont want to show 'void(0)' on status bar ...

Comment: Add `return false` after your onclick handler, to not follow `href`. Alternatively, you can add `javascript://` as a `href` attrbute.